# How to build a vector which contains the last n vectors of the output of deep neural network

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am using **keras**, **tensorflow 2.0**, to build a deep neural network, and I need to build another loss function based on the last `n = 4` outputs of the my model.

For example, I have the below DNN model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
X = Input(shape=(32,))
Y = Dense(32, activation= 'relu', kernel_initializer=ini)(X)
```

The output size of this model is a vector `Y` whose size is 32; what I need is to define another vector `Z` which contains the last 4 vectors of `Y`, for example `Z = [Y_4, Y_3 , Y_2 , Y_1]` which will be in this case size of 128.

I need to use that vector `Z` to build another loss function, so during the training, I will have the output of my DNN model `Y` and another vector `Z` which will be updated following the last coming vector `Y`.

I am expecting to get a vector `Z` with size of 128 containing the last 4 outputs of my DNN model. I fact, I couldn't start trying that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want `Z` to be the last 4 items in your model output `Y`, which is then used to calculate your loss function. Then will this help?

```py
def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = y_pred[-4:, :]
    # Your code here

# init the model as usual
model = Model(...)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_loss_fn)
```

Comment: What do you mean by y_pred? You mean I  should do test after each training operation to get the output of my DNN? I didn't do the training for my model yet, I'm still building it. I mean how can I get the vector y_pred?  Could you please write your code with more details? .. Thank you

Comment: `y_pred` is your `Y`. You don't need to do anything since the model auto recognizes `y_true` as the labels and `y_pred` as the last layer output.

Comment: That means setting Z = Y[:，:  -4]  or y_pred = Y[:，: -4]  will return the newest outputs of my DNN model with size of  four times of the output Y, is that right?

Comment: No, `[:, :-4]` means take all of the elements in the first dim and only take the last 4 elements in the second dim

Comment: When I followed your way, I got the following output `Y` is a `KerasTensor withe shape (None, 32)` and `y_pred` is a `KerasTensor withe shape (None, 28)`.  However, I expect to find an output y_pred with dimension (None, 128)

Comment: Where `None` would be 4 right? I edited my answer, please take a look

Comment: Also my mistake: `[:, :-4]` is "take all elements until the last 4 in the second dim", not that "last 4 elements" as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: It is the same :). I still get a vector whose size `(None, 32)`  however I expect to get the last four output `Y` which should be of size `128`

Comment: I'm sorry but I am confused here. The output of your model is `(None, 32)` where `None` is the batch size. There is no way you can produce a 128 size vector unless you do some transformations, such as element concat.

Comment: I know, but I need first to have the vector whose size is `128`  or in other way `(4,32)`; that is what I am looking for. In other words, the vector which will contain the last four outputs of the DNN.

Comment: As I said the first dim is the batch size, which will not be displayed for you. Try using my answer.